# T-SQL: different results from self join-s

Tags: sql-server, self-join

Could you please help me?
Why two codes below return different results? I am new to SQL and was taught that both codes are considered as self joins. What am I missing?
The required result is a table with country names and population as a percentage from the population of Bangladesh.

```
select a.name, 
       format(cast(a.population as float)/cast(b.population as float), 'p2') as percentage_from_Bangladesh
from bbc a, bbc b
where b.population = (select population from bbc where name = 'Bangladesh')
```

and

```
select a.name, 
       format(cast(a.population as float)/cast(b.population as float), 'p2') as percentage_from_Bangladesh
from bbc a join bbc b on a.name = b.name
where b.population = (select population from bbc where name = 'Bangladesh')
```

Comment: Because the first query, using the ***long deprecated*** (since SQL-92 in 1992) comma-separated list in  `FROM` clause style doesn't define a **join** condition (the `on a.name = b.name` part in the second query) and thus causes a cartesian product between the two joined tables ....

Comment: Evolve - do not use [old-style join via where clause](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 0):

First example (deprecated SQL syntax) is missing the where clause to indicate column on which to join the two tables.

```
select a.name, 
       format(cast(a.population as float)/cast(b.population as float), 'p2') as percentage_from_Bangladesh
from bbc a, bbc b
where a.name = b.name
and b.population = (select population from bbc where name = 'Bangladesh')
```